# Can you use a variable into an argument in c++?

Tags: c++

I am making a simple mp3 player and I want to involve user input as part of a mciSendString function in c++ where the user can enter the mp3 file name and it is appended to the mciSendString argument. My code is as follows

```
string x;
mciSendString(_T("open \"x\" type mpegvideo alias mp3"), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

You see, obviously trying `\"x\"` does not work... String x is where I plan to use cin.get for the user to enter the mp3 filename. The _T stands for text. Please go easy on me as I am a noob.

Comment: perhaps you can use append method to construct the whole string?

Comment: [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)? Or [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) (which `std::format` is based on)? Or [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)? Or just construct in-place when creating the string using the normal `+` operator?

Comment: What is `_T()`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ • `_T("string")` is a Windows macro that appends `L` if wide characters (UTF-16 on Windows) are enabled, or just the string otherwise (what Microsoft calls ANSI mode, although, ironically, the character sets are not ANSI).

Comment: @Ejay I know, but does the OP? This limits what could be placed there, thus passing some variably constructed string must be passed to `mciSendString()` in a different way, without using `_T()` at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ • Aye, using `_T` macro while trying to embed a C++ variable in a string like a JavaScript template literal string or a Python 3 `f` formatted string... well, that's not going to work so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. Based off @Remy's answer, I concatenated the strings and used `c_str()` function. Thank you all anyways for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stringstream` from `<sstream>` should be a familiar way to concatenate some strings.

```
std::stringstream x;
//put all the things you need in
x << "open " << x << " type mpegvideo alias mp3";
mciSendString(x.str().c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: You can’t use the `_T()` macro on non-literal strings.  If you are compiling for Unicode, `mciSendString()` will call `mciSendStringW()` which expects a `wchar_t` string. Use `mciSendStringA()` for `char` strings: `mciSendStringA(x.str().c_str(), ...);`

Comment: Fixed, but leaving as the macro because I believe it a better practice to not pick and choose the wide/ansi version since it may be changed and the two should not be mixed.

Comment: To make this fully portable for the current encoding in the project, use a `std::basic_stringstream<TCHAR>` instead.